Is there a difference between "floppy disk" and "diskette"?
It seems to me like "floppy disk" and "diskette" refer to the same thing, a device with a flat magnetic disk inside a square container, that is really floppy (less on 3"1/2). The most common name seems to be "floppy disk", at least in America.
Is there really no difference between the terms "floppy disk" and "diskette"?

Note that ‘floppy’ refers to the magnetic disk itself, not to its jacket/sleeve/enclosure — and as such, it applies equally well to the 3½", which is just as floppy if you extract it.

Also note that for magnetic media, the spelling is ‘disk’ even in UK English (which uses ‘disc’ for other meanings, including optical media).

The English spelling is 'disk' now, US terms regrettably having taken over.  But this is Retrocomputing, and there are plenty of fine old British computers that had magnetic discs.  But no 'discettes' :-)

@dave As a Canadian and, thus, used to a mish-mash of American and British English, I'll say that my perception has been that disc is only not used for magnetic media because the protective outer shell is non-removable. Intuitively, optical media is a disc because it's visibly like a discus, while other kinds of media are a disk because the most you can strip it down to without voiding the warranty isn't round. (i.e. It's a "disk" because you can't see the "disc(s)". A CD in a caddy is a disc because the caddy is conceptually a separate item. etc.)

...in fact, now that I think about it, I'm also feeling a "Wait... Americans use the disk spelling for things where conceptual roundness is significant, as opposed to something that's more just thin, flat, and without corners like "spinal disk/disc"? I suppose it had to come from somewhere... but Americans are weird." reaction.

 Actually the container is generally rectangle, not square. See these variants. 

@dave "discette" would be pronounced differently, like "discern".

@rexkogitans I agree with this idea generally, but English is infamous for its inconsistency between pronunciation of similarly-written words. E.g. "sceptic" isn't pronounced as "septic", even though its spelling looks the same as in "science".

Magnetic media is "disk", optical media is "disc", because it just happened to become popular that way. There's no actual difference in meaning between the words.

If you think 3½-inch diskettes seem rigid, try the less widespread 3-inch media.  You'll find that the magnetic surface inside the case is just as flexible, of course.

@thebusybee, yeah. I saw that now trying to measure my 3"1/2 floppy.

@ssokolow Americans, at least sometimes, do use a "c" spelling for round things. For example, the square thing you put in the drive is a "disk" or "diskette," but the round thing inside that is a "cookie."

No difference.
"Diskette" is what IBM called it when they introduced it.
"Floppy" is the vernacular.
The IBM Diskette and its implications for minicomputer systems.

Both Wiktionary and Wikipedia agree: ‘diskette’, ‘floppy disk’, ‘floppy diskette’, and ‘floppy’ are all pretty much synonymous.  (I'd assumed that ‘diskette’ was only for the smaller formats: 5¼", 3½", 3" — but no, it was coined for the original 8".)

The original 8” floppy was smaller than the removable hard disk packs, so, yes, the diminutive -ette was added

yes, they were cute little buggers, these 8" diskettes :-D

One could add that 'Diskette' is the German word for floppy disk. Maybe this is based on IBM being more successful in pushing their terminology but I don't know.

@quarague I believe variants of diskette are predominately used in most European languages.

@JonCuster Interesting!  I had always assumed the diminutive was added at the transition from 8" to 5¼".

@quarague, in Portuguese, we say "disquete", which is a spelling adaptation of English diskette. Oddly, its gender changes between Portugal (fem.) and Brazil (masc.).

Compared to the IBM RAMAC (fifty 24"  platters) or the KDF9 disc unit (seventeen 31" platters), everything is tiny.

@jkej yes, that's how we spell it in Dutch as well.

@Theodore - The Oxford English Dictionary suggests 1973 for the origination of the term. Collins says 1970-1975. Either clearly predates the 5¼" floppy.

And, dave's link above is a June 1973 announcement by IBM of the diskette. Whether the term existed before or not, I don't know.

@JonCuster The paper Dave linked says (emphasis added) ' In 1971, IBM started producing computer systems using a new form of magnetic storage medium. The medium, ultimately named "diskette" ', so presumably the name was applied (at least by IBM) some time between 1971 and 1973, but not at introduction.

@Spehro'speff'Pefhany: or possibly was used at introduction, just not during (all of) development (though I'll admit that seems less likely).

@JonCuster, I'd also suggest some influence from the fact that floppies were encased disks, and a perceived analogy with a "cassette" for small, lightweight, encased tape spools.

I knew a South African who insisted that the 3.5" diskette, being in a hard case, was not a floppy at all, but a stiffy. He cheerfully asserted "That's what we call them," clearly unaware of another British meaning.

@AndrewLeach former South African here, that's 100% true, I was very surprised to find out that in other countries, they weren't called stiffys, it just seemed so logical soft 8" = floppy, hard 3.5" = stiffy. We also had a lot of other local vocabulary that English speaking people outside the country found weird, e.g. traffic lights are "robots".

It might be useful to add that Diskette as diminutive of Disk is a rather logical choice, as (exchangeable) disks of that time used a stack of 14 inch platters. An 8" floppy was less than a third of the size (area) of a real disk - not to mention the even more reduced height, which was a good 8 inch in itself :)

For common speech, I agree with the accepted answer. However, I haven't seen anyone disambiguate the terms, and there is a difference.
"Floppy disk" covers all of the size and housing variants (8-inch, 5.25-inch, 3.5 inch). The disk is the round piece of thin flexible plastic inside the housing. It's "floppy" (i.e. flexible) as opposed to "hard" (as in "hard drive" or "hard disk drive").
"Diskette" is a portmanteu, combining "disk" and "cassette". The cassette is the hard plastic housing and its spring-loaded shutter.
Alternate technologies used hard disks inside cassettes too. Jaz disks are "hard diskettes" (a hard disk inside a cassette) but they're just referred to using the brand name.

Do you have any evidence that diskette is a portmanteau of disk and cassette? All the etymological resources I can think of disagree and give the more obvious and straightforward etymology that it’s simply disk with the diminutive suffix -ette. The term diskette was likely influenced by the similarly formed cassette (from casse ‘case’ + -ette, formed in French), but that doesn’t make it a portmanteau.

Agreed. ette is a common suffix, often diminutive.

But the whole answer is I think wrong. Claiming that "diskette" is a combination of the recording medium and the (hard plastic) housing is just wrong -- there were 8" diskettes which possessed neither a hard plastic housing nor a spring-loaded shutter.

I'm 95% sure I didn't just make up the origin of "diskette" although I did misremember that the earliest 8" floppies were also called diskettes (along with 5.25" floppies). I can't seem to find the source at the moment though. I remember that the technology was influenced by tape cassette data drives. I believe the first floppies had 4 partitions because data cassettes had 4 tracks. I'll try to find my source and update my answer.

I used 8" floppies which were labelled as 'diskette'. They had no partitions. I can say that without hesitation because the on-disk structure did not even have the concept of partition.

See page 1-9: picture of IBM-labelled 8" diskette in a DEC RX01 floppy drive user's manual

The term Diskette was originally coined by IBM as a Diminutive of Disk - after all, any prior disk was 14", so 8" was quite small. Calling it Floppy as well is a later addition.
